# Is there a simple image processing library for Java similar to ImageMagick?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-manipulation, gd

I am aware that Java includes very advanced image processing API's but what I'm looking for is a pure Java API (uses Java2D) that is "phrased" in terms more appropriate to common tasks of web image processing i.e. I want to write:

```
image.scale(0.2)
```

instead of

```
AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform(...)
t.resize(...)
t.translate(...)
AffineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(...)
etc. etc.
```

Think ImageMagick or GD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own wrapper classes around Java's ImageIO libraries that gives you the method signatures you need.

Comment: Yes, I could do this. The question is, is this the best (only?) option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no java native equivalent for the full functionality of ImageMagick that I know of.  However there are two java bindings for ImageMagic:  [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/) and [IM4Java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Java2D library creates memory leaks on Tomcat 6:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51687

If you are on 7 you should be good to use it.